# VirtualStringTree - how to get node from absolute index?

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview

Lets say i'm using a **VirtualStringTree** in virtual mode.

I want to indicate that the tree has some nodes:

```
VirtualStringTree1.RootNodeCount := 999983;
```

And since this tree is in *virtual* mode:

- all data management happens in the application
- and on demand

## Now sometime later i want to mark a node as [**Selected**](https://documentation.help/VirtualTreeview/TBaseVirtualTree_Selected.html)

Something has happened in my underlying [**TList**](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Athens/en/System.Classes.TList) (*e.g.* at index `797,977`) that would cause one of the nodes (if it's visible) to need to change its **`Selected`** status.

Since everything in a virtual tree is based on [**Node.Index**](https://documentation.help/VirtualTreeview/TVirtualNode.html#:%7E:text=record%0A%20%20ChildCount%3A%20Cardinal%3B-,Index%3A%20Cardinal%3B,-NodeHeight%3A%20Word%3B%0A%20%20States), ideally there would be a way to indicate that an **index** is selected:

```
VirtualStringTree1.RootNodeCount := 999983;
VirtualStringTree1.Selected[797977] := True; //indicate that node at index 797977 is now selected
```

But the tree doesn't have an overload to set selection by index.

The only method to alter a node's selected state is to:

- ***have*** a `PVirtualNode`
- pass that to `VirtualStringTree1.Selected[node] := True;`

How can i mark a node as selected, when i don't have the node?

## Windows ListView solution

A Windows **ListView** control in virtual mode solves it pretty simply.

- everything is based equivalently on `Node.Index`
- and the control uses callbacks to ask the application *on demand* for display information

So you are given a `LVN_GETDISPINFO` callback. And that is when you populate the [callback structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-lvitema), and give the tree the information it is asking for on demand:

- Text
- State (e.g. Selected)
- ImageIndex
- Indent

But for simplicity you can think of it as:

```
procedure TForm1.VirtualStringTree1GetSelected(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode; var Result: Boolean);
begin
   Result := True; //yes, this node is selected
end;
```

And so the way i would mark an item in the tree as **Selected** is i would call:

```
ListView1.Invalidate;
```

If the item #797,977 is currently on screen: it will redraw during the next paint cycle as selected.

What's the **Virtual Treeivew** equivalent of marking a node as **Selected** when all you have is a virtual-mode index?

## Hack

```
function GetNodeByIndex(Tree: TVirtualStringTree; Index: Integer): PVirtualNode;
var
   node: PVirtualNode;
begin
   Result := nil;

   node := Tree.GetFirstChildNoInit(nil);
   while Assigned(node) do
   begin
      if node.Index = Index then
      begin
         Result := node; 
         Exit;
      end;
      node := Tree.GetNextNoInit(node);
   end;
end;
```

But traversing a linked list of 797,977 items in order to get node **`n`** is very bad. It's on the order of **O(n)** bad.

Comment: You have the data in a TList. When you want a specific item in the list to be selected, just call vtreeview.Invalidate. GetText gives you node and node.index. If that matches your TList selection, just mark that node as selected.

Comment: @LURD I thought that was wonderfully, amazingly, sneaky - until i realized that the selection would not be valid unless the user first made that node visible. Until then the `getFirstSelected` would be incorrect. I have to **set** the node selected.

Comment: I see the predicament now. When RootNodeCount is set, use the OnInitNode event to store the node pointer in your TList. Would that be possible? (Or store it in another crossref list).

Comment: You can make (and maintain) dynamic array of nodes. There is no other way than the mentioned traverse.